# Contar registros só se maiores que o datetime atual, com count()

Tags: php, mysql, join, where

Tenho a seguinte *query*:

```
SELECT u.nome, u.email, u.login, u.data_cadastro, COUNT(*) AS qtd
FROM patrocinadores AS p
   LEFT JOIN anuncios AS a ON a.id_user = p.id_user
   INNER JOIN usuarios AS u ON u.id = p.id_user
WHERE p.id_patrocinador = '1' GROUP BY a.id_user
```

Ela puxa todos os cadastros que foram patrocinados pela ID `1`. E também me retorna quantos anúncios cada cadastro patrocinado tem.

Esse comando funciona perfeitamente, só que preciso puxar somente a quantidade de anúncios ativos, ou seja, só quando a coluna `expira > time()`.

Quando deixo a *query* assim, com o `WHERE a.expira > '...'`,

```
SELECT u.nome, u.email, u.login, u.data_cadastro, COUNT(*) AS qtd
FROM patrocinadores AS p
   LEFT JOIN anuncios AS a ON a.id_user = p.id_user
   INNER JOIN usuarios AS u ON u.id = p.id_user
WHERE p.id_patrocinador = '1' AND a.expira > '1449365367' GROUP BY a.id_user
```

ela só me retorna os registros em que `a.expira` é maior que o tempo atual. Eu quero que retorne todos, mas se o tempo da coluna for menor que o tempo atual então ele conta como 0 aquele registro.

Só quero fazer um sistema que conta quantos anúncios as contas que são do patrocinador `1` tem ativos.

Comment: Acho que só isso já resolve: `SUM( IF( a.expira > 1449365367, 1, 0 ) )`

Comment: @Bacco creio que sua resposta resolveu!!!! ... Coloca como resposta e eu escolho como correta ;) ... Obrigado por você e pelo Ricardo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu sugeriria usar isto:

```
SUM( IF( a.expira > 1449365367, 1, 0 ) )
```

Explicação:

O `SUM` serve para somar valores de um campo, e com base nisso criamos um "campo" especial que vai nos dar 1 para todos os casos que queremos contar, e zero para os que não.

A função `IF` cai como uma luva neste caso, pois vai retornar 1 se `a.expira > 1449365367`, senão, zero. A sintaxe da função IF é esta:

```
IF( condição, resultado se positivo, resultado se negativo)
```